# Is it possible to reach the center of Giant's Deep?

Tags: outer-wilds-alpha

There is a planet in [Outer Wilds](http://alexbeachum.com/archives/258) that seems to be made almost entirely of water.  The description for this planet is as follows (taken from the in-ship computer).

[image: None of our spacecraft have ever been able to penetrate beyond the outer atmosphere]

> None of our spacecraft have ever been able to penetrate beyond the outer atmosphere

Sure enough, when I try to fly my way into the center, I can pass through the (surprisingly stormy and hazardous) atmosphere, and only seem to get a short distance into the first layer of water.

[image: Ship is in underwater limbo]

I'm at full throttle in this image, and as you can see, I'm now approaching the core at 0 m/s, which I guess means I'm stopped.  I can toss probes towards the center, and they too end up hanging in underwater limbo a short distance ahead of me.

Is it possible to reach the center somehow?

Comment: This looks sounds like a wall for content that will be added later in development to me.

Comment: I've determined how to do it, but I'll wait and see if someone else would care to post the answer first.  :)

Comment: @GnomeSlice Probably safe to post by this point. I can confirm you can get in there, but I managed it by semi-accident. :(

Comment: @AllenGould I'll post maybe tomorrow.  I want to get screenshots and stuff from a couple of different places.  Check in again tomorrow night or later this week!

Comment: @AllenGould Sorry, going to have to do a raincheck on that.  Something came up at home.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theres an uncommon cylcone that spins the opposite way, which can be seen demonstrated on Brittle Hollows' abandoned observatory.  Find the reverse cyclone and you'll be forced into the water layer of the planet, and free to roam inside the core.