# Where can I find the Quantum Moon?

Tags: outer-wilds-alpha

I've managed to explore every last planet I've found in *Outer Wilds*, but I can't seem to find the last Unexplored Location in my computer.

[image: Computer screen showing Unexplored Location]

I know from [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/129578/is-it-possible-to-reach-the-center-of-giants-deep) that the name of that location is the Quantum Moon. The problem is, I have no idea how to find it.

I'm beginning to suspect it is the moon that changes shapes when no one is watching it, and it may be invisible. I'm starting to suspect the moon is actually the Night Vale Clock Tower, because I just can't see it.

**How do I find this (possibly) invisible, (possibly) teleporting moon?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Quantum Moon is definitely not invisible, although it jumps around a lot so it can be tricky to find if you don't know what you're looking for.

The Quantum Moon moves around the solar system when you look away from it, so if you find
it, you need to keep it in your view as you approach it, or you'll have to find it again.

---

First things first, here's what you're looking for:

[image: The Quantum Moon as seen through the telescope.]
*The Quantum Moon as seen through the telescope.*

At first it might be easy to confuse this with the standard moon orbiting around *Timber Hearth*, but there's an easy way to tell it apart from a distance.  Haul your telescope out, and if you can see a plume of smoke rising from the object (see below), then it isn't the moon you're looking for; the home planet's moon has a campfire!

[image: The moon of Timber Hearth]

If this isn't helping, the Quantum Moon will also play an eerie ambient noise which you can hear through the telescope when you point it at it.

---

### Locations

There are four (possibly five, although that's a spoiler for another day) locations that the moon can appear in.  Basically, you can find it in orbit around the following planets:

- Timber Hearth
- Hourglass Twins
- Brittle Hollow
- Giant's Deep

Now for some screenshots (looks like I forgot the Timber Hearth one, whoops):

[image: Quantum Moon at Hourglass Twins]
*Quantum Moon at Hourglass Twins*

[image: Quantum Moon at Brittle Hollow]
*Quantum Moon at Brittle Hollow*

[image: Quantum Moon at Giant's Deep]
*Quantum Moon at Giant's Deep*

---

There's some vague information about the Quantum Moon hidden away on one of the planets, in an alien device you can translate.  Spoiler below for the planet.

> Giant's Deep, inside a short building on one of the islands.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've flown around a bit and get a sense for what each system's "normal state" is, you can use your map and zoom in and look for a moon that's not supposed to be there (and since it orbits one of the existing planets, it's a fairly fast check). You can even lock on to it from the map screen.

*Getting* on the Quantum Moon is a whole other kettle of fish. :)

Comment: After release note: Observing the QM through the map counts as observing the QM. The map is rendered somewhat useless because of it.